# Service Call to Read Messages from Shared Mailbox with Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

With a service I am able to get a list of users from our Azure tenant but I am unable to give the service app the correct permissions to read messages to a shared mailbox. The follow code is a stripped down version of the code, the userid is the guid associated to the user account for the shared mailbox.

```
private const string AuthorityFormat = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0";
private const string GraphScopeDefault = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
private const string GraphUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0";
private const string RedirectUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient";

public static async Task GetMailAsync(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret, string redirectUri, string userId ) {

  var daemonClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithAuthority(string.Format(AuthorityFormat, tenantId))
    .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

  var authResult = await daemonClient.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] {GraphScopeDefault}).ExecuteAsync();

  async Task AuthenticateRequestAsyncDelegate(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage) => requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authResult.AccessToken);

  var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(GraphUrl,new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticateRequestAsyncDelegate));

  var messages = await graphClient
    .Users[userId]
    .Messages
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
}
```

This is the resultant error:
**Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: ErrorAccessDenied
Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.**

I have confirmed through exchange powershell scripts that the App-Id has access to this mailbox:

```
Test-ApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity sharedmailbox@foo.bar -AppId {appId guid}
```

With the following response: **AccessCheckResult : Granted**

The API permissions granted and yes they have been approved by the admin:

[image]

The same code calling the users api works:

```
var userPage = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

Any idea what could be the problem? Is there any logs in the Azure App Portal that could tell me what the problem could be with failed attempts?

Thanks in advance!

acg

***** UPDATE *****

The issue is mailbox specific, whether using my code or Jeremy's both get the same error with one of our shared mailboxes but work complete fine with another.  Both of the mailboxes show that permissions are granted through the powershell command, any way to get more details from logs or events in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using ClientCredentialsProvider https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantID)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
```

Please check out our latest SDK documentation on how to create a Graph Client
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?tabs=CS

Comment: Hi Jeremy still the same problem, assuming there is no other magic to be done other than:       var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(GraphUrl, authProvider);

      var messages = await graphClient.Users[userId].Messages.Request().GetAsync();

Comment: Hi Jeremy, so its definitely mailbox specific, any thoughts as to how to identify the missing attribute/permission on a mailbox that would cause this error? Thanks!

Comment: I'm following up internally. If you have Premiere support, you may want to go through portal.office.com and raise a support ticket. We cannot support you here if we start sharing mail box id's etc.

Comment: in the mean time, could you provide the request-id that came back in your response?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, my apologies, since I do not know the implications of passing request ID's around I would rather hold off from sharing that information here.

Comment: I understand, the request-id (correlation id) can only be used by microsoft engineering in searching our logs in the back end. the request-id is not a token and can't be used by anyone externally to obtain information.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, pardon the radio silence, you still available to look at those logs?

Comment: if you can share a request-id i can look at it